# Suppose that $E(X| Y,Z,W) = E(X|Y)$, is it true that $E(XZ| Y) = E(X|Y)E(Z|Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X,Y,Z,W$ are all random variables.

If we have that $E(X| Y,Z,W) = E(X|Y)$,

is it true that $E(XZ| Y) = E(X|Y)E(Z|Y)$ and that $E(XW| Y) = E(X|Y)E(W|Y)$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes 
$$E(XZ\mid Y)=E(E(XZ\mid Y,Z,W)\mid Y)=E(ZE(X\mid Y,Z,W)\mid Y)=E(ZE(X\mid Y)\mid Y)=E(X\mid Y)E(Z\mid Y),
$$ 
using the "tower" property, then "taking out what is known". This is conditional independence.